# Se SQL statetement beeing run within a procedure with SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

This is not directly a programming question but I ask it anyway because it's related to `debugging`.

I wonder if it's possible to see exactly what `SQL` statements that are being executed within a procedure in Microsoft `SQL` Server Profiler?

For now I just see the procedures being called but due to complicated procedures causing a tricky bug somewhere I would like to see exactly what `SQL` statement being executed. So it would be nice if anyone has any tip on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Add [`SP:StmtStarting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188243.aspx) and/or [`SP:StmtCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx) to the events you are tracing.